# Label (pre)Collision with label

Tags: vba, label, collision-detection, point

I'm doing some game stuf, and i'm having problens with the collion test.
What i'm trying to do is check if a coordenate is empty, so the player can move.
This is what i have so far, but it doesnt work...

```
Function ColissionWithPoint(ByVal Lbl1 As Label, ByVal Lbl2 As Label) As Boolean
    Dim pUp As New Point(Lbl1.Location.X - 1)
    Dim pDown As New Point(Lbl1.Location.X + Lbl1.Height + 1)
    Dim pLeft As New Point(Lbl1.Location.Y - 1)
    Dim pRight As New Point(Lbl1.Location.Y + Lbl1.Width + 1)
    If pDown.Equals(Lbl2.Bounds) Or pUp.Equals(Lbl2.Bounds) Or pLeft.Equals(Lbl2.Bounds) Or pRight.Equals(Lbl2.Bounds) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```